# How to reverse y axis in an AreaChart

Tags: java, gwt, google-visualization

I am using [Google Chart Tools (aka Visualization) 1.1 Library](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-apis/wiki/VisualizationGettingStarted) with GWT to display an AreaChart and I would like to know how to reverse the y axis? 
There is

```
setReverseAxis(boolean)
```

when you set the Options but this one reverse the x axis. I don't find how to set the y axis.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The current version of Google Visualization API that is used in GWT Visualization 1.1.1 doesn't support all available functionalities. Until Google release a new version of its API for GWT, I think a possible workaround is to extend AreaChart.Options class by adding a new native method like this one (I didn't try but it should work, if the version loaded by viz api 1.1.1 support already this option) :

```
/**
 * Change the vertical alignment.
 * @param align possible values : -1 or 1
 */
public native final void setVerticalAlignment(int align) /*-{
    this.vAxis.direction = align;
}-*/;
```

**EDIT:**
After digging a little bit with the api, I found that corechart.Options has a method to specify axis properties:

```
Options options = AreaChart.createOptions();
AxisOptions verticalOptions = AxisOptions.create();
verticalOptions.setDirection(-1);
options.setVAxisOptions(verticalOptions);
...
... 
AreaChart area = new AreaChart(data, options);
```

Comment: How do I extend AreaChart.Options class?

Comment: I've edited my answer. It exists two AreaChart class, one is depecrated and doesn't offer the possibility to inverse yAxis...

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I was using GWT Visualization 1.1.0 that doesn't implement the possibility to reverse yAxis so I changed for 1.1.1 and added your code.